# How do you add type hints for a function with specific keyword arguments?

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing, mypy

I want to add type hints to a higher order function whose input (also a function) has specific keyword arguments.

My code looks similar to this:

```
def foo(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    ...


def bar(c: Callable[[int, int], int]) -> int:
    return c(a=1, b=2)  # getting a mypy error: Unexpected keyword argument "a"
```

In the example, I want to be able to call `c` from the function scope of `bar`, and I want to be able to assume it has keyword arguments `a` and `b`.

I can see why mypy would complain here, since some other function with a different signature could be passed in as an argument to `b` and then `c(a=1, b=2)` would no longer work. But it seems like there should be a way to add the keyword argument names in the type hint, to explicitly guarantee that function `c` takes arguments with names `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [mypy extension](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/additional_features.html#extended-callable-types) for extending `Callable`

```
from typing import Callable
from mypy_extensions import (Arg, DefaultArg, NamedArg,
                             DefaultNamedArg, VarArg, KwArg)
                             
def foo(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    ...


def bar(c: Callable[[Arg(int, 'a'), Arg(int , 'b')], int]) -> int:
    return c(b=1, a=2)  # no issues
```